# Update using subquery and Case statements

Tags: sql, oracle, vertica

I was writing a update query with some case statements. when case doesn't satisfy it will update the column with NULL.
Following is the query :

```
 UPDATE TGT
 SET C1 = CASE WHEN TGT.c2 = SRC.c2 AND SRC.C3 = 'P' THEN SRC.C1 ELSE NULL END,
     C4 = CASE WHEN TGT.c5 = SRC.c5 AND SRC.C3 = 'D' THEN SRC.C4 ELSE NULL END
    FROM SRC;
```

It is always populating NULL even data is existing in the Source table.

Thanks In Advance for help.

Comment: Does this query run, without updating anything, or does it give an error?

Comment: Nope, This is a single query. It updates all the records in the table but with NULL value ONLY.

Comment: And is this Oracle?

Comment: This is invalid syntax. You probably have that CASE inside a subquery? As in SET C1 = (SELECT CASE ...)?

Comment: Both Oracle and Vetica.

Comment: @Goran : This is like subquery in Update statement. It should not be a problem I guess. It was not giving any compile error.

Comment: It looks as if you need a script that only updates column C1 to null if rules are not satisfied. If rules are satisfied you are not doing anything - column value stays the same. Is this the case?

Comment: Case expressions, not statements...

Answer (score 2):

Oracle does not support `from` or `join` in the `update` statement.  You can use a subquery, however:

```
UPDATE TGT
    SET C1 = (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                FROM SRC
                                WHERE TGT.c2 = SRC.c2 AND SRC.C3 = 'P'
                   THEN TGT.C1 ELSE NULL
              END);
```

Note:  The above will update all rows.  If you just want to update rows that don't match, then use `not exists` in the `where` clause:

```
UPDATE TGT
    SET C1 = NULL
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM SRC
                      WHERE TGT.c2 = SRC.c2 AND SRC.C3 = 'P'
                     );
```

Comment: This can be tried when we are updating only 1 column. If more than 1 columns need to be updated then it won't help. It might give performance issues as well i Guess. Any thoughts??

Comment: @Biswabid: if you need to update more then one column use something like `set (c1, c2, c3) = (select x1, x2, x3 from ...)`

Answer (score 0):

You want to set `c1` null where no related 'P' record in `src` exists. Use `NOT EXISTS` hence:

```
UPDATE tgt
SET c1 = NULL
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT *
  FROM src
  WHERE src.c2 = tgt.c2 =  AND src.c3 = 'P'
);
```

**UPDATE:** You have just changed your question and it is now two different fields that you want to set null in two different circumstances. I suggest you simply use two statements then: The above for `c1` and a similar for `c4`. No need to make things more complicated than they really are.